# How to obtain timer functionality using boost in c++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, timer

My app is a multithreaded application where I create a thread which keeps on reading data on socket to check notification from server continuously and other thread sends requests to server after every time t(say 20 sec).
I am using boost for doing same.
I read about boost::asio and I found a timer function deadline_timer().But as per my understanding it fires only once asynchronously but my requirement is continuous calls to send everytime timer t expires.
How shall I implement it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at the asio samples

Comment: @sehe: I looked at it.Correct me if I am wrong in understanding.I understand it can fire only once timer expires but what if i need to keep calling a function every t time interval?

Comment: This is a classic threading problem. You should read up about `<thread>`, Boost.Thread, or pthreads.

Comment: @erip: I understand that, I am already using many threads using boost in my app ,also even this is present in separate thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply fire the timer again from it's handler:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
using namespace std;

int stop_after = 3;

void async_wait_timer(boost::asio::deadline_timer& t, int seconds)
{
    t.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds{1});
    t.async_wait(
        [&] (const boost::system::error_code& e)
        {
            --stop_after;
            if(!e || !stop_after)
            {
                async_wait_timer(t, seconds);
            }
        });
}

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service svc;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer timer{svc};
    async_wait_timer(timer, 1);
    svc.run();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But where will my function reside in your code? As in where will I call my function?

Comment: You would call it wherever it was appropriate to do so.  In the above example, I just wanted to illustrate how to re-fire a timer.  If you don't know where you need a timer, that is a separate (and out of scope) question.

Comment: Got it !! My question was regarding call as previously I was using t.async_wait(func) to fire my function but in your sample code you are using t.async_wait() to fire timer again but if that's the case i need to change my logic.
anyway thanks for your prompt reply. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Solve the requirement by putting a continuous loop with deadline_timer within it till my system shuts down.

```
while(!shutdown==true) 
{   
    boost::asio::io_service io;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(10));           timer.async_wait(&check_faults);
    io.run();
 }
```

If someone can provide better approach please post your comment, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: The other answer is the better approach, typically

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an example: 
A Cross-Platform Flexible Timer Scheduler for C++20 applications (Header-Only Class): https://github.com/AmitGDev/Scheduler/blob/master/Scheduler/Scheduler.h

Use it like this:

```cpp
    #include <syncstream>
    #include <iostream>
    #include "Scheduler.h"


    int main()
    {
        class Model final
        {
        public:

            void Test()
            {
                std::cout << "Re-activate the timer 5 times" << std::endl;

                scheduler_.ScheduleTimer(1, 1000, &Model::OnTimer, this, 5); // <-- 

                // Sleep to allow the timer to work.
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(6));
            }

        protected:
            Scheduler scheduler_{};

            void OnTimer(uint64_t timer_id, uint8_t n) // n - Extra parameter
            {
                if (n > 0) {
                    std::osyncstream sync_stream(std::cout);
                    sync_stream << "timer " << timer_id << " expired" << std::endl;

                    scheduler_.ScheduleTimer(timer_id, 1000, &Model::OnTimer, this, n - 1); // <--
                }
            }
        };

        Model model{};
        model.Test();
    }
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/-NlYrY7k4)

Or like this:

```cpp
    #include <syncstream>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <atomic>
    #include "Scheduler.h"
    

    int main()
    {
        class Model final
        {
        public:

            void Test()
            {
                std::cout << "Re-activate the timer 6 seconds" << std::endl;

                scheduler_.ScheduleTimer(1, 1000, &Model::OnTimer, this); // <-- 

                // Sleep to allow the timer to work.
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(6));
                
                exit_ = true;
                
                // Sleep to allow the timer to exit.
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
            }

        protected:
            Scheduler scheduler_{};
            std::atomic_bool exit_{ false };
            
            void OnTimer(uint64_t timer_id)
            {
                std::osyncstream sync_stream(std::cout);
                sync_stream << "timer " << timer_id << " expired" << std::endl;

                if (!exit_.load()) {
                    scheduler_.ScheduleTimer(timer_id, 1000, &Model::OnTimer, this); // <--
                }
            }
        };

        Model model{};
        model. Test();
    }
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/6Ccd1_cDx)